# Android Device Manager service: An automated desktop script

Tags: android, python, web-services

Saw another question on something similar to this, but it seemed to go unanswered.

**TLDR**: Lost my phone, someone said they found it and would return it. Never showed, looking to find an API for Android's Device Manager online utility.

Phone fell out of my pocket in a cab Saturday afternoon in airplane mode. Someone had turned off airplane mode on Monday and received a call from me, saying that they were the cab driver and would drop it off at my apartment. They never showed :(

I'm looking to write some sort of script that logs into Android Device Manager every ten minutes, and if it receives updated location data or even recognizes that it's turned on to email me and a million other people. I see no API's available for Android Device Manager, to which I ask: Am I looking in the wrong places? Or am I better off looking to find a library that can consume web pages and look for information? I seem to remember Python's library for this being pretty easy to use.

Comment: @Aashish, what's with moving the TLDR to the top?!

Comment: So that it could save experts time. If they would be interested, they can read it further.